# Calculate total sum for the grouping of child group using Aggregate sum or group by sum Expression

Tags: reporting-services, sum, aggregate, grouping, reporting

I am trying to calculate a sum based on Category of business

(Total sum of Type 1, Total sum of Type 2 and 3).

I created calculated fields for all 3 which is given below :

```
''=SUM(If(Fields!Category_of_business.Value="Type1",Fields!Selling.Value,0))''
```

For which I am getting an error that Aggregate functions are not allowed in calculated fields. Is there any workaround? [Visual rep of SSRS table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7j9pc.png)

Comment: The expression is wrong, it should be `IIF` not `IF`. after that you should be able to use the expression in a textbox that is within the row group you want to calculate